# angularjs ng-show vs new templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest

I have a Coupon project in Java including beans(Coupon, Customer, Company),
 DAO layer that connects with the DB, and  Facade Layer(CustomerFacade, CompanyFacade and Admin Facade).
I built Rest Services to connect with the Facades, now my question is about my Admin.html page and the Admin controller, as the Admin.html download it has 3 tabs(coupons, customers and companies), when the coupons tab pushed it expose the div with the coupons while hide the 2 other divs with the companies and the customers, now on every Coupon it show also a drop down table and can delete or update the coupon, so every push on update open a form that i fill and send the update, when the update complete and i want to show a message i need to hide all the other information so every method in the controller i finish with 7-8 ng show parameter turn to false and 1 to true and so on, a lot of mess.
my controller:

.controller('admin',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

```
$scope.tab = 1;

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/CouponWebService1/rest/admin/getAllCoupons")
    .then(function(response){ 
    $scope.coupons = response.data;
});
$scope.couponTable= true;        (hiding html element apart from 1)
$scope.companyTable= false;
$scope.customerTable= false;
$scope.successLog = false;
$scope.couponJointTable = false;

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/CouponWebService1/rest/admin/getAllCompanies")
.then(function(response){ 
    $scope.companies = response.data;
});


$http.get("http://localhost:8080/CouponWebService1/rest/admin/getAllCustomers")
.then(function(response){ 
    $scope.customers = response.data;
});

$scope.select = function(setTab) {
    $scope.tab = setTab;
    if (setTab === 2){
        $scope.couponTable= false; (hiding html element apart from 1)
        $scope.companyTable= true;
        $scope.customerTable= false;
      $scope.successLog = false;
      $scope.couponJointTable = false;
    }
    else if (setTab === 3){
        $scope.couponTable= false;  (hiding html element apart from 1)
        $scope.companyTable= false;
        $scope.customerTable= true;
        $scope.successLog = false;
        $scope.couponJointTable = false;
    }
    else{
        $scope.couponTable= true;
        $scope.companyTable= false;
        $scope.customerTable= false;
        $scope.successLog = false;
        $scope.couponJointTable = false;
    }
};
$scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
    return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
}
```

can you advice me how should i work can i change this working method to something more useful, maybe templates or something i dont realize?
thanks,

Comment: That's a very long sentence in your opening paragraph, you might want to split it up. Also, your question is open-ended and not suitable to this format.  Please ask a specific question, maybe about using a template, and why it didn't meet your requirements.  Then someone can give specific advice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the repetitive stuff into a helper function.

```
function hide_all_and_show_one(elem_to_show){
  var all = ['couponTable', 'companyTable', 'customerTable', 
             'successLog', 'couponJointTable'];
  all.forEach(function(val){ $scope[val] = false; });
  $scope[elem_to_show] = true;
}

$scope.tab = 1;

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/CouponWebService1/rest/admin/getAllCoupons")
  .then(function(response){ $scope.coupons = response.data; });
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/CouponWebService1/rest/admin/getAllCompanies")
  .then(function(response){ $scope.companies = response.data; });
$http.get("http://localhost:8080/CouponWebService1/rest/admin/getAllCustomers")
  .then(function(response){ $scope.customers = response.data; });

hide_all_and_show_one('couponTable');

$scope.select = function(setTab) {
  $scope.tab = setTab;
  if (setTab === 2){
    hide_all_and_show_one('companyTable');
  }
  else if (setTab === 3){
    hide_all_and_show_one('customerTable');
  }
  else{
    hide_all_and_show_one('couponTable');
  }
};

$scope.isSelected = function (checkTab) {
    return ($scope.tab === checkTab);
}
```